# text moves out of div when I change element display

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I'm working on a project where I have to tick a checkbox  if I want a one way flight or a flight with return . If I tick the box I want a single flight so I have only one input date to give . If I untick my box I want a flight with return so a second input to fill a return date appears .
When I load my app the box is unchecked so I have both inputs . The available routes are next to my inputs like below :

[image]

If I tick the checkbox above for a one way flight the return date dissappears and the display is like below as the position of my departure route changes :

[image]

Know if I untick my checkbox :

[image]

the positioning of the elements in my return route change as now my return word is not in the center and my destination is half outside my red element . Why is this happening and I cannot have the same state as my first pic ? I would appreciate your help .

My code to display the available routes :

```js
function showDate(){
            var checkbox = document.getElementById("transition");
            var backDate = document.getElementById("return-box");
            if(checkbox.checked==true){
                backDate.style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("ret").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("return-container").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("available-routes").style.top="300px";
            }else if (checkbox.checked==false){
                backDate.style.display="inline-block";
                document.getElementById("ret").style.display="inline-block";
                document.getElementById("return-container").style.display="inline-block";
                document.getElementById("available-routes").style.top="200px";

            }
        }
```

```css
.date{
  padding:20px;
}



#routes-container{
  position: relative;
  width:200px;
  height: auto;
}



#routes-container p{
  text-align:center;
}

#departure-container , #return-container{
  position: relative;
  width:200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: coral;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  padding:2px;
  border-radius:5px;
}


.dashline{
  position:relative;
  top:-3px;
}

.dep-time , .arr-time{
  font-size: 20px;
}

.location-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-left:3px;
  width:200px;
}

.location-container div{
  font-size:12px;
}

.dest{
  margin-left:auto;
}

.plane{
  margin-left:60px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
}

.d2{
  top:-3px;
}

.ret{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id = "check-t">
                    <label for="transition"> <span id = "simple"> <strong> Simple transition ? </strong> </span> </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="transition" name="transition-box" onchange="showDate()" >
                </div>


<div class="date" id="booked-dates">
                    <div id="departure-box">
                        <h3> Departure Date  </h3>
                        <input type = "date" name="dep-date" class = "booking-date" id="anaxorisi">
                    </div>
                    <div id="return-box">      
                        <h3> Return Date </h3>
                        <input type= "date" name= "return-date" class="booking-date" id="epistrofi"> 
                    </div>      
                </div>


<div class="date" id="available-routes">
  <h3> Available Routes </h3>
  <div id="routes-container">
    <p> Departure </p>
    <div id="departure-container">
      <span class="dep-time"> 13:00 </span>
      <span class="dashline">................ </span>
      <span class="arr-time"> 14:00 </span>
      <div class="location-container">
        <div> ATH </div>
        <div class="plane"> ✈️ </div>
        <div class="dest">
          KOS </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <p id="ret"> Return </p>
    <div id="return-container">
      <span class="dep-time"> 16:00 </span>
      <span class="dashline d2">................ </span>
      <span class="arr-time"> 17:00 </span>
      <div class="location-container">
        <div>
          KOS</div>
        <div class="plane"> ✈️ </div>
        <div class="dest dest2"> ATH </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Even in the above snippet which isn't my complete app the position of the elements in my return route element change positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the javascript to:

```
 function showDate(){
        var checkbox = document.getElementById("transition");
        var backDate = document.getElementById("return-box");
        if(checkbox.checked==true){
            backDate.style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("ret").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("return-container").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("available-routes").style.top="300px";
        }else if (checkbox.checked==false){
            backDate.style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("ret").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("return-container").style.display="flex";
            document.getElementById("available-routes").style.top="200px";

        }
    }
```

Does that fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that your javascript is setting the '#return-container' to be 'display: inline-block'

```
document.getElementById("return-container").style.display="inline-block";
```

Whereas to begin with it is set to 'display: flex'.

```
#departure-container , #return-container{
  position: relative;
  width:200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: coral;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  padding:2px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

You should have both using the same CSS. Either the JS should set 'display: flex' or the CSS be 'display: inline-block' to begin with.